# Angular 2: Route change still sending request in the network

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 2 for my project along with webpack.
So whenever I change a route, I still see a request in the network.

[image]

What's different from the normal process is that I am adding all the javascript bundles dynamically to index.html with head.js.
Reason for doing this is to be able to point the request to the local CDN server running on my machine.

The components have already loaded. Still requests are going when I visit that route and as webpack-dev-server has been configured to return index.html for every unresolved request, the response if index.html file.

Note: Everything is working fine. Issue is this extra request that goes every time I visit that route.

Comment: Please try using `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(..., {useHash: true})]`. If this request goes away it's caused by HTML5 pushState, and I guess you won't be able to get rid of that one then (except by switching to `HashLocationStrategy`).

Comment: Yes. I switched to usehash true and it works fine.

Comment: Is there any solution to getting the exact same thing with usehash false??

Comment: I guess not, this is why the server needs to support HTML5 pushState, while with HashLocationStrategy the server is not involved at all.

Comment: Perhaps https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145953

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Tried the same thing with SystemJS and it works well. I hope the webpack community would have added some workaround for it as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about TS build stuff because I'm only using Dart myself.

Answer (score 0):

Every route is a new component and it's dependencies have to be loaded since they are only loaded when needed.

Comment: Yes I understand but all these components are already loaded & if you check the image in the question you will see the request for every component going every time I visit that route.